# Как задать форму тексту с помощью css

Tags: html, css

Как задать форму тексту с помощью css?
 
Мне нужно, чтобы текстовый блок был в форме круга, а текст внутри его обтекал.

P.S.: Сам текст в дугу гнуть не надо))

Comment: какую форму текста вы хотите сделать?

Comment: Хочу сделать форму круга

Comment: Плохая идея.

Comment: Можно по подробнее?

Answer (score 3):

Если просто какой-то текст в области, ограниченной окружностью, то задаете размеры блока, скругление и overflow: hidden. word-break: break-all; создаст иллюзию обтекания а не грубого обрезания фрагмента текста. И меняете размер шрифта по необходимости. Шрифт обтекать не будет, он будет просто обрезаться по границе. Чтобы строки сохраняли читаемость, нужно осуществлять перенос в местах соприкосновения с границей если скругление по правому краю (для письма слева-направо). Но слева переноса нет, следовательно там текст будет резаться. Вообще, можно прийти к выводу, что хорошо бы, чтобы все изменения, связанные с размещением теста (выравнивание, переносы) осуществлялись в ограниченной окружностью области, в противном случае нам придется или подсчитывать ширину строк, играться с отступами, потому что бордер просто обрезает текст, а не задает размеры текстового блока, относительно которого работают переносы и т.д.

Вот сервис, делающий то, что, очевидно, Вам нужно, и тутор по его использованию:

http://www.csstextwrap.com/index.php

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tf1xWZQNCFQ

Путь, которым там действуют (там есть и вариант с JS, но нас сейчас я так понял интересен pure CSS), действительно связан с изменениями ширины строк как бы лесенкой. Сгененерируйте код и посмотрите сами.

Может в чем ошибаюсь, буду благодарен за критику.

Comment: Спасибо. Буду пробовать

Answer (score 0):

В будущем это будет делаться [нативными средствами CSS](http://html.adobe.com/webplatform/layout/shapes/)

А пока можно сделать так: много `div`'ов, половина `float: left`, половина `float:right`. И подбираются ширины. Сначала широкий `div`, потом уже, и так до середины, а потом обратно. Как-то так (полоски это невидимые div с `float: left`):

```
——————————————  А 

————————— вот вот вот вот

———— тут тут тут тут тут тут тут 

—— текст текст текст текст текст

———— произвольной произвольной


————————— формы формы


—————————————— ! ! !
```

Ну почти кружок ))

Answer (score -1):

Честно говоря с трудом понял вопрос, но могу предложить такое решение.
Для текстового блока сделать большой `border-radius`, чтобы блок был круглый, а тексту задать `text-align: justify;`
Может так?

```
div.textblock {
    text-align: justify;
    border-radius: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Зачем отвечать, будучи некомпетентным и не проверяя ответ? Обтекание будет по прямоугольному блоку, без учтения `border-radius`

Comment: А хотя да, верно. Тогда вручную подгонять текст, или использовать js.